# How to solve android error which says onClick exceeded 65535 bytes limit

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   //this contains 4,095 if conditions
}
```

The code is inexecutable because it says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
 -implements android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick
 -The code of method onClick(View) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit
```

Can anyone help me solve this one? because i actually need those 4,095 if conditions in my code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way than having 4095 ifs. If you post some of the code we might give you some ideas how to implement it differently. If that's not what you want how about splitting the code into several methods?

Comment: yes that exactly what i want..splitting the code into two parts but still using 1 button.. @Emanuel

Comment: can you tell us what you are trying to do. We can help if we can optimize the if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the 4095 if statements then I'd do something like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (! processPart1(v)) {
            processPart2(v);
        }
    }

    private boolean processPart1(View v) {
        if (q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked() && !q3.isChecked() && !q4.isChecked() && !q5.isChecked() && !q6.isChecked() && !q7.isChecked() && !q8.isChecked() && !q9.isChecked() && !q10.isChecked() && !q11.isChecked() && !q12.isChecked()) { 
            // do your thing
            return true;
        }
        else if (!q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked() && !q3.isChecked() && !q4.isChecked() && !q5.isChecked() && !q6.isChecked() && !q7.isChecked() && !q8.isChecked() && !q9.isChecked() && !q10.isChecked() && !q11.isChecked() && !q12.isChecked()) { 
            // do your thing
            return true;
        }
        // more conditions here...
        return false;
    }

    private void processPart2(View v) {
        // more conditions
    }
```

However you can implement this much faster and also easier to modularize:

```
    boolean q[] = {q1.isChecked(), q2.isChecked(), q3.isChecked(),
                   q4.isChecked(), q5.isChecked(), q6.isChecked(),
                   q7.isChecked(), q8.isChecked(), q9.isChecked(),
                  q10.isChecked(), q11.isChecked(), q12.isChecked()};
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = q.length; i < len; i++) {
        value += (q[i] ? 1 : 0) << i; 
    }

    switch(value) {
    case 0: // do your thing
    case 1: // do your thing
    case 2: // do your thing
    // more case statements ...
    }
```

While your code has to go through 2048 if statements in average the code above processes merely 12 values and then jumps directly to the correct case statement. It's also much less error prone and can be split into different methods easily like this:

```
processValues0To1023(value);
processValues1024To2047(value);
processValues2048To3071(value);
processValues3072To4095(value);

private void processValues0To1023(int value) {
    switch(value) {
    case 0: // do your thing
    // more case statements ...
    }
}

private void processValues1024To2047(int value) {
    switch(value) {
    case 1024: // do your thing
    // more case statements ...
    }
}

private void processValues2048To3071(int value) {
    // ditto
}

private void processValues3072To4095(int value) {
    // ditto
}
```

Comment: how can i add another 2 process.? so there's a total of 4 process..can you show me the  syntax.?thank you.. @Emanuel

Comment: I extended the example to have 4 methods